# cannot find symbol variable ArrayIO

Tags: java, arrays, symbols

I'm building a program to compute the psnr (Peak Signal to Noise Ratio) of two images. I'm getting the following error when compiling the below code:

```
Psnr.java:35: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable ArrayIO
location: class Psnr
ArrayIO.readByteArray(args[2], img1, nrows, ncols);
```

Psnr.java

```
import java.io.*;

public class Psnr {

  public static double log10(double x) {
    return Math.log(x)/Math.log(10);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    int     nrows, ncols;
    int     img1[][], img2[][];
    double  peak, signal, noise, mse;

if (args.length != 4) {
  System.out.println("Usage: Psnr <nrows> <ncols> <img1> <img2>");
  return;
}
nrows = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
ncols = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
img1 = new int[nrows][ncols];
img2 = new int[nrows][ncols];
ArrayIO.readByteArray(args[2], img1, nrows, ncols);
ArrayIO.readByteArray(args[3], img2, nrows, ncols);

signal = noise = peak = 0;
for (int i=0; i<nrows; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<ncols; j++) {
    signal += img1[i][j] * img1[i][j];
    noise += (img1[i][j] - img2[i][j]) * (img1[i][j] - img2[i][j]);
    if (peak < img1[i][j])
      peak = img1[i][j];
  }
}

mse = noise/(nrows*ncols); // Mean square error
System.out.println("MSE: " + mse);
System.out.println("SNR: " + 10*log10(signal/noise));
System.out.println("PSNR(max=255): " + (10*log10(255*255/mse)));
System.out.println("PSNR(max=" + peak + "): " + 10*log10((peak*peak)/mse));
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to correct the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayIO is not a class from the `java.io` package. You need to import the correct package (`import` statement) and add the library to your classpath (ArrayIO is not part of the Java API)

Comment: What would that be? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Can't find it too - I never heard of a class named `ArrayIO` for Java. Google didn't help too... Maybe you took/adapted the code from another source, please have a look there. Maybe it was a different programming language?